# Tufte-handout caption overlapping figure

Tags: pgfplots, tufte

I am attempting to display three figures, side by side in a table.  I've placed the table inside the figure* environment to make the table the full width of the page, however the corresponding caption then overlaps the table.  I can hackishly fix this by appending an empty row to the bottom of the table and making it sufficiently large, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Here is a model working example

```
\documentclass[nohyper,nofonts]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\emptyfig}{\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth/3,height=\textwidth/3]%
            %\addplot[black] coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) };
    \end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \emptyfig & \emptyfig & \emptyfig \\
            Hi & Hi & Hi
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This is an overlapping caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

and the corresponding output.
[image: Model working example output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your `tabular` environment in a command that makes a box, such as `makebox`:

```
    \makebox[\textwidth]{%
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \emptyfig & \emptyfig & \emptyfig \\
            Hi        & Hi        & Hi
        \end{tabular}%
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[nohyper,nofonts]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\emptyfig}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \makebox[\textwidth]{%
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \emptyfig & \emptyfig & \emptyfig \\
            Hi        & Hi        & Hi
        \end{tabular}%
    }
    \caption{This is an overlapping caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this issue a "feature" of tufte-handout?

Comment: @jotagah no, I believe it's because of the use of a `tabular`

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, there are other solutions:

## Option 1

Simply add `\vspace*{desired space}` before the caption:

```
\documentclass[nohyper,nofonts]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\emptyfig}{\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth/3,height=\textwidth/3]%
            %\addplot[black] coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) };
    \end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \emptyfig & \emptyfig & \emptyfig \\
            Hi & Hi & Hi
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \caption{This is an overlapping caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

## Option 2

Use optional parameter for the `\caption` command:

```
\documentclass[nohyper,nofonts]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\emptyfig}{\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth/3,height=\textwidth/3]%
            %\addplot[black] coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) };
    \end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \emptyfig & \emptyfig & \emptyfig \\
            Hi & Hi & Hi
    \end{tabular}
    \caption[][6mm]{This is an overlapping caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```